# WARNING:tensorflow:The default stddev value of initializer will change from "1/sqrt(vocab_size)" to "1/sqrt(dimension)" after 2017/02/25

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I got this warning message when set Deep Model.

Warning message

> WARNING:tensorflow:The default stddev value of initializer will change
>   from "1/sqrt(vocab_size)" to "1/sqrt(dimension)" after 2017/02/25.

My code

```
deep_columns = [
  tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(workclass, dimension=8),
  tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(education, dimension=8),
  tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(gender, dimension=8),
  tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(relationship, dimension=8),
  tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(native_country, dimension=8),
  tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(occupation, dimension=8),
  age, education_num, capital_gain, capital_loss, hours_per_week
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't explicitly [give an initializer function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column.py#L990-L993) to `embedding_columns`, tensorflow will use the default initializer, which is a normal with `0` mean and `1/sqrt(vocab_size)` standard deviation as the code below:

```
if initializer is None:
      ...
      stddev = 1 / math.sqrt(sparse_id_column.length)
      initializer = init_ops.truncated_normal_initializer(
          mean=0.0, stddev=stddev)
```

That is just a warning that the default initializer function is going to be slightly changed in near future (although it looks like they were a bit late on the deadline). Nothing important and shouldn't effect your work (can take more or less time to converge but difference should be unnoticeable).

If the warning disturbs you, you can give an [initializer function explicitly](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal_initializer) when creating embedding columns or you can ignore warnings by setting verbosity to errors only. `tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)`